# Understanding some SQL subquery examples

Tags: mysql, subquery

I've been self-learning SQL from resources on the internet. I have two SQL queries that I would like to understand.

1. Write an SQL query to fetch three max salaries from a table.

`SELECT distinct Salary from worker a WHERE 3 >= (SELECT count(distinct Salary) from worker b WHERE a.Salary <= b.Salary) order by a.Salary desc;`

2. Write an SQL query to fetch three min salaries from a table.

`SELECT distinct Salary from worker a WHERE 3 >= (SELECT count(distinct Salary) from worker b WHERE a.Salary >= b.Salary) order by a.Salary desc;`

As you can see these two are similar. The part I don't particularly understand is this:

`(a.Salary >= b.Salary)` or `(a.Salary <= b.Salary)`

I don't understand its logic here. What is it doing here?

Table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your query for each given salary it is calculated how many salaries are more/less than current. If count is more than 3, then the current one shouldn't be shown. The conditions `(a.Salary >= b.Salary)` are responsible for counting salaries more/less then the current one.

But to get 3 min/max salareis I would do thise:

```
SELECT slary
FROM worker
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

For min:

```
SELECT slary
FROM worker
ORDER BY salary ASC
LIMIT 3;
```

If one worker can have more than one record and you need to show the max total, this would be:

```
SELECT SUM(slary) total_salary
FROM worker
GROUP BY worker_id
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 3
```